# $(this).attr("href") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, this line of code is returning undefined for `$(this).attr("href")`

```
$("a").attr("href", "javascript:page('" + $(this).attr("href") + "')");
```

How can I get that value?

Comment: Linking to javascript is smelly. If it's possible, use events instead

Comment: Using "javascript:" URLs is kind-of ugly. Why not use a "click" handler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    page(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$("a").attr("href", function (index, oldHref) {
    return "javascript:page('" + oldHref + "')");
});
```

Check out the documentation for [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for information about the overload that takes a function reference.

Although as @Pointy points, out, you should consider writing an event handler instead of using `javascript:` inside your markup.

Comment: Probably a good idea to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` here, but yes.

Comment: @Pointy I don't get it. It's not a good idea to use `javascript:` instead of a click handler in the first place:X

Comment: @Esailija I agree - I just typed in a comment on the OP to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative approach that doesn't require Javascript on your href attribute

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    page(this.href);
} )
```

Comment: Your code has a bug: an extra close parenthesis. It should be `.click( function(e) { ...`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need inline javascript, why not do like below:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    page(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that (update all href attribute of the links on the page) you could do

```
$("a").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("href", "javascript:page('" + $(this).attr("href") + "')");
});
```